# After Changing text in setting activity,it is not getting reflected

Tags: android, android-studio

Am making my first android application with the help of Udacity's tutorial(Weather App).

For setting activity, I have one text box,which holds the location value.

For example say, Texas.
But when am changing that to any other value,it's not reflecting the same in the app. Though,the value in that text box is getting changed.

In the app's SettingActivity I have following code,

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
```

But as of today `addPreferencesFromResource` is deprecated,so am not really sure how to proceed in this regard. What do I change it with?

My goal is to change the value in Location's text and when I go on my mainActivity,the weather data should reflect the changed location's data.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
    private void updateWeather()
    {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        SharedPreferences prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        String location=prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),getString(R.string.pref_location_default));
        weatherTask.execute(location);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        updateWeather();
    }
```

Above is the code through which I update the value.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
               bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));
        setupActionBar();
   }
```

Above is the code from settingActivity. But as I said, `addPreferencesFromResource` is deprecated. So this part of code is not really working.

Comment: can you post a bit more of your code.

Comment: private void updateWeather()
    {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        SharedPreferences prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        String location=prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),getString(R.string.pref_location_default));
        weatherTask.execute(location);
    }
-------------------------------This is the updateWeather Function. I need to change the pref_location_key.

Comment: @driftking9987 post on question with formating

Comment: Yeah Sure.Am posting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate class as below to handle all the prefs related operations, storing and restoring...

```
public class MyPrefs {
Context context;
SharedPreferences systemPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

static MyPrefs prefs;

public static final String DEFAULT_LOCATION = "DEFAULT_LOCATION";
public static final String SOME_DEFAULT_LOCATION = "London";

public static MyPrefs getInstance(Context context){
    if(prefs == null){
        prefs = new MyPrefs(context);
    }
    return prefs;
}

private MyPrefs(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.systemPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.USER_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    this.editor = systemPrefs.edit();
}

public String getDefaultLocation(){
    return systemPrefs.getString(DEFAULT_LOCATION, SOME_DEFAULT_LOCATION);
}

public void setDefaultLocation(String newLocation){
    editor.putString(DEFAULT_LOCATION, newLocation);
    editor.commit();
}

public void clear() {
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

And to use this in any activity class...

```
        MyPrefs myPrefs = MyPrefs.getInstance(this);
    //To get the location stored in prefs
    String locationFromPrefs = myPrefs.getDefaultLocation();

    //To store the location in prefs
    myPrefs.setDefaultLocation("New York");
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I added the first code snippet in the settingActivity and then used the second one to get the value,but it ain't working. Thanks though.

Comment: whats the issue? You got no value? Did you debug?

Comment: Yeah,I debugged. The issue is that,in the text box,where am writing the location,that is getting changed but on the main activity,am getting the data for default location which I hardcoded. My main problem is that,how do I save the change after I edit in setting as addPreferencesFromResource is not working. Everywhere I search,this keyword is always there but now it's not working.

Comment: May be you override the updated value by that default value again somewhere...Wait I will update my code in few mins